# Flushing a pipe's buffer

Tags: c, pipe

I was playing with pipes, and took the following code from [here](https://www.gidforums.com/t-13116.html); Once I understood I'm witnessing a block-buffering issue, I added a calling to `sleep()` that wasn't present in the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *ps_pipe;
    FILE *grep_pipe;

    int bytes_read;
    int nbytes = 100;
    char *my_string;
  
    char buffer[100];

    /* Open our two pipes */
    ps_pipe = popen ("ls", "r");
    grep_pipe = popen ("sort", "w");

    /* Check that pipes are non-null, therefore open */
    if ((!ps_pipe) || (!grep_pipe))
    {
      fprintf (stderr,
               "One or both pipes failed.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    bytes_read = 0; 
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ps_pipe)) 
    { 
        fprintf(grep_pipe, "%s", buffer);
        bytes_read += strlen(buffer); 
    } 

    printf("Total bytes read = %d\n", bytes_read); 
    sleep(2);

    /* Close ps_pipe, checking for errors */ 
    if (pclose(ps_pipe) != 0) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not run 'ps', or other error.\n"); 
    } 
    
    /* Close grep_pipe, cehcking for errors */ 
    if (pclose(grep_pipe) != 0) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not run 'grep', or other error.\n"); 
    } /* Exit! */ 
    
    return 0; 
}
```

EDIT [It's wrong, see answer below]: <s>This way, I made sure that the pipe's buffer got flushed once the programed returned from its main function.</s>

However, I still don't understand the reason: why would a pipe's kernel buffer be flushed to stdout? What does the former has to do with the latter? [EDIT: this is wrong, too, but was left for context]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sleep has no effect on any kernel buffers.

The output you see on `stdout` is coming from the `sort` process, and is triggered by closing the `grep_pipe`.

Your program is in effect emulating the following shell script:

```
ls | sort
```

You open a pipe to read from `ls`, consume all of its output (from its `stdout`) and send this output to the `stdin` of the `sort` process.  The `sort` can't sort the lines until it has all the lines, and it only knows it has all of the lines when its `stdin` is closed, which happens when you close the `grep_pipe`.

Once `grep_pipe` is closed, the `sort` does its work, producing the sorted lines to its `stdout`.  The `pclose` does not return until the associated process has terminated, at which point the `sort` will have finished producing all of its output.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it.